# Would boiling water kill microorganisms in clothing that had feces spilled on it?

Tags: infection

Lets say there is a piece of clothing that had a small amount of human feces that spilled on it.

Would placing that clothing in boiling water destroy the microorganisms on that clothing?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about health or domestic science rather than biology.

Comment: It has nothing to do with health or domestic science.  It is about biological concepts and biological mechanisms.

Comment: 1. The question you quote is just a question from one person expressing his opinion in the same way as I was. His opinion is not SE policy, and mine is not unless four other list members with sufficient privilege vote to close your question.  2. I do not think disinfecting clothing is to do with either biological concepts or mechanisms. 3. If your comments are addressed to a particular poster you should include an @ followed by his name. That way he will be notified of your posting.

Comment: Whether boiling water is hot enough to kill skatole, stercobilin, haem, bilirubin and biliverdin are biological concepts.

Comment: *...kill skatole, stercobilin, haem, bilirubin and biliverdin...* -- these are names of chemicals, but your question asks about microorganisms. Are you interested in the denaturing / removal of chemicals or the killing of microbes?

Answer (score 1):

Using boiling water alone will not destroy all the toxic compounds found within faeces. One example is skatole, this is found in faeces and is partially responsible for the foul smell faeces gives off. By laundry I assume you mean laundry detergent? If so, it would depend on the detergent being used.

I hope this answered your question :)